# Teamviewer Chrome Extension - What Does Network Traffic Look Like?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

If I run the Teamviewer Chrome extension to connect to a remote system, what does the network traffic look like?  That is, does it just look like regular "https" requests or could it be identified as "remote access"?

Answer (score 0):

Per the Teamviewer website - https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Which-ports-are-used-by-TeamViewer/ta-p/4139

> TeamViewer is designed to connect easily to remote computers without
>   any special firewall configurations being necessary. In the vast
>   majority of cases, TeamViewer will always work if surfing on the
>   internet is possible. TeamViewer makes outbound connections to the
>   internet, which are usually not blocked by firewalls.
>
> However, in some situations, for example in a corporate environment
>   with strict security policies, a firewall might be set up to block all
>   unknown outbound connections, and in this case you will need to
>   configure the firewall to allow TeamViewer to connect out through it.
>   TeamViewer's Ports
>
> These are the ports which TeamViewer needs to use: TCP/UDP Port 5938
>
> TeamViewer prefers to make outbound TCP and UDP connections over port
>   5938 – this is the primary port it uses, and TeamViewer performs best
>   using this port. Your firewall should allow this at a minimum. TCP
>   Port 443
>
> If TeamViewer can’t connect over port 5938, it will next try to
>   connect over TCP port 443.
>
> However, our mobile apps running on Android, iOS, Windows Mobile, and
>   BlackBerry don't use port 443.
>
> Note: port 443 is also used by our custom modules which are created in
>   the Management Console. If you’re deploying a custom module, eg.
>   through Group Policy, then you need to ensure that port 443 is open on
>   the computers to which you’re deploying. Port 443 is also used for a
>   few other things, including TeamViewer update checks. TCP Port 80
>
> If TeamViewer can’t connect over port 5938 or 443, then it will try on
>   TCP port 80. The connection speed over this port is slower and less
>   reliable than ports 5938 or 443, due to the additional overhead it
>   uses, and there is no automatic reconnection if the connection is
>   temporarily lost. For this reason port 80 is only used as a last
>   resort.
>
> Our mobile apps running on Android, Windows Mobile, and BlackBerry
>   don't use port 80. However, our iOS apps can use port 80 if necessary.
>   Android, Windows Mobile, and BlackBerry
>
> Our mobile apps running on Android, Windows Mobile, and BlackBerry can
>   only connect out over port 5938. If the TeamViewer app on your mobile
>   device won’t connect and tells you to “check your internet
>   connection”, it’s probably because this port is being blocked by your
>   mobile data provider or your WiFi router/firewall. Destination IP
>   addresses
>
> The TeamViewer software makes connections to our master servers
>   located around the world. These servers use a number of different IP
>   address ranges, which are also frequently changing. As such, we are
>   unable to provide a list of our server IPs. However, all of our IP
>   addresses have PTR records that resolve to *.teamviewer.com. You can
>   use this to restrict the destination IP addresses that you allow
>   through your firewall or proxy server.
>
> Having said that, from a security point-of-view this should not
>   really be necessary – TeamViewer only ever initiates outgoing data
>   connections through a firewall, so it is sufficient to simply block
>   all incoming connections on your firewall and only allow outgoing
>   connections over port 5938, regardless of the destination IP address.

They didn't specify for the Chrome extension, but I would bet that it is the same as the client.  At a cursory glance I didn't see anything to indicate otherwise.  I guess the most conclusive way to find out would be to run wireshark and find out.